# CSS Class is not applying to element (border width,color,and style attributes)

Tags: html, css

Hello working on a course over at freecodecamp.com and I am supposed to add border width color and style to an image via a class.

I am not having luck getting it to take though. I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

```css
.thick-green-border {
  border-width: 10px border-color: green border-style: solid;
}
.red-text {
  color: red;
}
h2 {
  font-family: Lobster, Monospace;
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Monospace;
}
.smaller-image {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<h2 class='red-text'>CatPhotoApp</h2>

<img class='smaller-image thick-green-border' src='https://bit.ly/fcc-kittens' />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a couple semi-colons:

```
border-width:10px border-color:green border-style:solid;
```

Should be:

```
border-width:10px; border-color:green; border-style:solid;
```

Modified Code:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
  .thick-green-border{
    border-width:10px; border-color:green; border-style:solid;}
  .red-text {
    color: red;}

  h2 {
    font-family: Lobster, Monospace;}

  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Monospace;}

  .smaller-image {
    width: 100px;}
</style>

<h2 class='red-text'>CatPhotoApp</h2>

<img class='smaller-image thick-green-border' src='https://bit.ly/fcc-kittens'/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You would need to separate each property in `border-width:10px border-color:green border-style:solid;` with a semicolon like `border-width:10px; border-color:green; border-style:solid;`

```css
  .thick-green-border {
    border: 10px;
    border-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
  }
  .red-text {
    color: red;
  }
  h2 {
    font-family: Lobster, Monospace;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Monospace;
  }
  .smaller-image {
    width: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<h2 class='red-text'>CatPhotoApp</h2>

<img class='smaller-image thick-green-border' src='https://bit.ly/fcc-kittens' />
```

Comment: thank you :) i wont admit how many times i looked over that > . >

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
.thick-green-border{
 border:10px solid green;
 }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frykaroh/)